# Jetpack Compose MutableState not updating on the screen

Tags: viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a movie list from Firebase realtime database, but I'm not getting the list from the ViewModel.
When I update the `apiResource.data` in the Repository, it is not updating the mutableList on the screen.

Screen:

```kotlin
           val movies = viewModel.data.value.data?.toMutableList()

           if (viewModel.data.value.loading == true) {
               CircularProgressIndicator()
           } else {
              
               movies?.forEach {
                   Log.d("Movies", it.name)  // I'm not getting the movie list on the screen
               }

           }
```

ViewModel:

```kotlin
val data: MutableState<ApiResource<List<Movie>, Boolean, Exception>> = mutableStateOf(
        ApiResource(null, true, Exception(""))
    )

    private fun getMovies() {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            data.value.loading = true
            data.value = repository.getAllMovies()

            if (data.value.data.toString() != "[]") {
                data.value.loading = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```kotlin
class Repository {
    private val apiResource = ApiResource<List<Movie>,Boolean, Exception>()

    suspend fun getAllMovies(): ApiResource<List<Movie>, Boolean, java.lang.Exception> {

        try {
            apiResource.loading = true

            var movies: List<Movie>

            Firebase.database.reference.child("movies").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    movies = dataSnapshot.children.map { snapshot ->
                        snapshot.getValue(Movie::class.java)!!
                    }

                    apiResource.data = movies  // set data in apiResource
                    if (apiResource.data.toString() != "[]") {
                        apiResource.loading = false
                    }

                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
            })
        } catch (exception: java.lang.Exception) {
            apiResource.e = exception
        }
        
        return apiResource
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose cannot track changes of an object contained by a mutable state. It can only track updates to the value of the mutable state.

Possible solutions:

1. Updating your mutable state by creating a copy of the object with the updated properties. Data class is extremely handy in this case:

   ```kotlin
   data class ApiResource(val isLoading: Boolean = false)

   class VM : ViewModel() {
       var apiResource by mutableStateOf(ApiResource())

       fun update() {
           apiResource = apiResource.copy(isLoading = true)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Making the necessary properties of `ApiResource` mutable states.

   ```kotlin
   class ApiResource {
       var isLoading by mutableStateOf(false)
   }

   class VM: ViewModel() {
       val apiResource = ApiResource()

       fun update() {
           apiResource.isLoading = true
       }
   }
   ```

The second problem with your code, is that you're messing coroutines with asynchronous code. `addValueEventListener` is not gonna wait until `onDataChange` is called, so `getAllMovies` always returns an empty object.

To make a coroutine wait until an async call finishes, you need to use `suspendCoroutine`.

Also, listener provided to `addValueEventListener` can be called multiple times if result changes. Your current code doesn't expect that, I suggest you using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead.

```kotlin
val movies = suspendCoroutine<List<Movie>> { continuation ->
    Firebase.database.reference.child("movies").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            continuation(
                dataSnapshot.children.map { snapshot ->
                    snapshot.getValue(Movie::class.java)!!
                }
            )
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}
```